# Checking reflect.Kind on interface{} return invalid result

Tags: go, reflection, types, slice

I have some question about Go reflect behaviour.

I have a slice named `src` defined in `[]interface{}` type. I'd like to get the actual type of each element within the slice. This is what I did:

```
src := []interface{}{"noval", 0, nil}
srcType := reflect.ValueOf(src)

for i := 0; i < srcType.Len(); i++ {
    each := srcType.Index(i)

    if each.Interface() == nil {
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is nil")
    } else {
        switch each.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is string")
        case reflect.Int, reflect.Int16:
            fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is int")
        default:
            fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is ?")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
value noval is ?
value 0 is ?
value <nil> is nil
```

For some reason, the data type of element `"noval"` is not detected as `string`, hence the `default` block is executed within the `switch`.

Also the `0` value should be identified as `reflect.Int` but the `default` block is called again.

Can somebody enlighten me please, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src` is a slice whose element type is `interface{}`. So each element you obtain is of static type `interface{}`, so their "kind" will be `reflect.Interface`. Adding a new `reflect.Interface` case will reveal that:

```
case reflect.Interface:
    fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is interface")
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TY0l0KrWrIO)):

```
value noval is interface
value 0 is interface
value <nil> is nil
```

If you want the "wrapped" element in the interface, use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem):

```
} else if each.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
    switch each.Elem().Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is string")
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int16:
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is int")
    default:
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is ?")
    }
}
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/31k3afRfehv)):

```
value noval is string
value 0 is int
value <nil> is nil
```

Also note that you're "switching" over the *kind* of the values, not over their actual *types*. What this means is that values of multiple types may end up in specific cases, like in this one:

```
type mystr string
src := []interface{}{"noval", 0, nil, mystr("my")}
srcType := reflect.ValueOf(src)

// ...
```

Output of this will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F84qLLlVcY2)):

```
value noval is string
value 0 is int
value <nil> is nil
value my is string
```

The value `mystr("my")` is detected as `string`, because it is of `string` *"kind"*, but its type is not `string` but `mystr`. This may or may not be what you want. If you want to distinguish between a value of type `string` and `mystr`, then you should "switch" over the actual *type* of values like in this example:

```
} else if each.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
    switch each.Elem().Type() {
    case reflect.TypeOf(""):
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is string")
    case reflect.TypeOf(0):
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is int")
    case reflect.TypeOf(mystr("")):
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is mystr")
    default:
        fmt.Println("value", each.Interface(), "is ?")
    }
}
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/InetxrB5QeI)):

```
value noval is string
value 0 is int
value <nil> is nil
value my is mystr
```

As you can see `"nova"` is detected as a value of type `string`, and `mystr("my")` is properly detected as a value of type `mystr`.

Also note that for what you're trying to do, you don't need reflection, just use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

```
src := []interface{}{"noval", 0, nil}
for _, v := range src {
    switch v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println("value", v, "is string")
    case int:
        fmt.Println("value", v, "is int")
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("value", v, "is nil")
    default:
        fmt.Println("value", v, "is ?")
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P0wytfG4Yq6)):

```
value noval is string
value 0 is int
value <nil> is nil
```